# Can XDocReport convert pptx to pdf?

Tags: java, converters, xdocreport

I'm currently using XDocReport to convert docx, odt and pptx to Pdf. But my problem is that I can't find sample demo to convert pptx to pdf. Can someone help me?

Comment: I do not know XDocReport but found [this](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/PPTXReportingJavaMain) on github (PPTXReportingJavaMain). Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

XDocReport doesn’t provide this kind of converter pptx -> pdf. Any contribution are welcome!
- from one of the XDocReport developer